# CREATE VIEW joining two tables, only displaying rows from the first table with the most recent date in the second table

Tags: mysql, view, mysql-5.0

I have multiple tables. My main table has a composite key consisting of a phone number and an order number.

I want to create a VIEW where only the subscriptions with the most recent order date are displayed. I've searched around, but I can't find out how to do this.

My current setup (greatly simplified) is as follows:

```
+-----------------+       +-----------------+
|  SUBSCRIPTIONS  |       |  ORDERS         |
+-----------------+       +-----------------+
| * phone_number  |\      | * order_number  |
| * order_number  |->---+-|   date          |
|   name          |/      |   merchant_id   |
|   other_stuff   |       |                 |
+-----------------+       +-----------------+
```

I am trying to create the following table:

```
+------------------------+
|  latest_subscriptions  |
+------------------------+
| * phone_number         |
| order_number           |
| date                   | 
| merchant_id            |
| name                   |
| other_stuff            |
+------------------------+
```

**Edit:** I've now managed to create a view using the following query:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=MERGE DEFINER=`removed`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `subscriptions_with_order_data` AS select `subscriptions`.`subscription_id` /*I use this as for linking another table I haven't mentioned here, namely "transactions", where each transaction gets assigned this ID instead of the composite key so it is possible to change the phone number and order number without having to modify the data in the transactions table*/ AS `subscription_id`,`subscriptions`.`phone_number` AS `phone_number`,`subscriptions`.`order_number` AS `order_number`,`orders`.`date` AS `subscription_date`,`orders`.`merchant_id` AS `merchant_id`,`subscriptions`.`name` AS `name` /*Lots of other column names ommitted*/ FROM (`tblprefix_subscriptions` `subscriptions` left join `tblprefix_orders` `orders` on((`orders`.`ordernumber` = `subscriptions`.`ordernumber`)));
```

However, phone numbers still aren't unique.

Comment: Can you not create a view or the query for the view? But seeing as you must have a 1:1 connection between Subscriptions and Order (because otherwise you cannot know which subscription is the 'newest one' ) - it looks like a simple inner join between for example a sub query finding the latest order per merchant and then the subscription table.

Comment: @Allan I'm having trouble creating the query. (I've now created a view joining both tables, though. See my edit to the post.)